# Handle password reset with Azure B2C in .Net Core Web Api

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a web API that allows users to sign in or sign up with Azure B2C. I'm using the  *sign-up or sign-in policy*, which gives me a "Forgot your password?" link. Clicking on this link gives me an *access_denied* with an error description of **AADB2C90118**.

How do I handle this error in my web API?

Note: I'm using a [customized authentication UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) for the sign-in/sign-up form.

Comment: Have you defined and configured a password reset policy? When you do, make sure the Identity provider you're using is enabled in the reset policy.

Comment: Yes, I've defined and configured a password reset policy as well as enabled the reset policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [wingtips sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c).

Note that this mainly shows that your application needs to do a redirect when this error occurs. Not sure what role you want your API to play.

Specifically look for the error code AADB2C90118 you mentioned:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AADB2C90118&type=

Conroller action to handle the reset:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipIdentityWebApplication/Api/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L252

Some code taken from there:

```
 options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();

                    if (context.ProtocolMessage.Error == "access_denied" && context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.StartsWith("AADB2C90118"))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
                    }
```

And

```
        var openIdConnectAuthenticationOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
 [...]
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {

                OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                {
 [...]
                    // Handle the error that is raised when a user has requested to recover a password.
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Failure.Message) &&
                        context.Failure.Message.Contains("access_denied") &&
                        context.Failure.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect($"/Account/RecoverPassword?ReturnUrl={context.HttpContext.Items["redirect_uri"]}");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                    }
```

Comment: Not sure how using OpenId will work with the way I have my API set up. I'm using Jwt Bearer middleware to handle token validation, but it seems like the samples are not using it. [Here is the example I used](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi). Basically, how can I handle the error code and redirect with this example?

Comment: Try debugging AuthenticationFailed in startup.cs or look at the other events of JwtOptions. But you might need to change your application itself to handle the error, I assume you have more than just an api and the login screen?